# How to write to pointer directly using gets() function?

Tags: c, pointers, gets

I got these test code and just curious, why passing pointer to gets() results in a runtime error?

```
void main()
{
    char *value="gogo";
    puts(value);
    value="11";
    puts(value);
    gets(value);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The pointer `value` points to (the static array associated with) a string literal.

Attempting to modify a string literal has undefined behavior. In this case, your compiler stores the string `"gogo"` in memory marked as read-only by the operating system, and attempting to modify it causes your program to crash.

If you declare a pointer to a string literal, you should define it as `const`:

```
const char *value = "gogo";
```

so the compiler will diagnose any attempt to modify it. Or, if you really want to modify the string, define it as an array:

```
char value[] = "gogo";
```

which the means that you can't assign a value to `value`, but you can use `strcpy` to update it.

Some more problems:

`void main()` is wrong [*]; the correct definition is `int main(void)`. If you're using a book that told you to use `void main()`, please get a better one; its author does not know C very well.

Never use the `gets` function; it is inherently unsafe, and has been removed from the language. (It cannot guard against input longer than the array into which the value is stored.) You can use `fgets` instead; it's a bit more complicated to use, but it can be used safely.

You need to add

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

to the top of your source file to make these functions visible. If your compiler didn't complain about calls to undeclared functions, find out how to increase its warning level.

[*] Saying that `void main()` is wrong slightly overstates the case. A conforming compiler *may* permit it, and no compiler is required to complain about it, but there is no good reason to take advantage of that. `int main(void)` is always correct. Any C book or tutorial that advocates using `void main()` was almost certainly written by someone who does not know C well enough to be writing books or tutorials about it.

Comment: Remember that `void main()` is blessed by MSVC — terrible though the decision is, on Microsoft platforms, `void main()` is a platform-specific alternative way of defining `main()`.

Answer (score 1):

Here, your pointer points to a string literal (`"gogo"`). String literals are not guaranteed to be writable. You need to allocate your own memory:

```
char value[50] = "gogo";
...
gets(value);
```

However, **this is not safe**, as `gets` does not take the size of the buffer, and thus might overflow your buffer. (Which could also lead to a runtime error). **NEVER** use `gets`, as the manpage states:

> **BUGS**
>
> Never use `gets()`.  Because it is impossible to tell without knowing the data in advance how many characters `gets()`  will  read,  and because `gets()` will continue to store characters past the end of the buffer, it is extremely dangerous to use.  It has been used to break computer security.  Use `fgets()` instead.

Much better to allocate your own memory:

```
char user_input[200];
fgets(user_input, 200, stdin);
```

You might need to check `user_input`, to see if it ends with a newline. If it does, then `fgets` read a whole line. If it doesn't, then the the user typed more than ~200 characters into the line, and you'll need to read more to get the whole line. I've used `200` here. Choose a size that makes sense for your data. You can also use `malloc` to allocate memory on-the-fly, and put fgets into a loop in order to read an entire line into a buffer.

Answer (score 1):

Because `char *value="gogo";` is more likely than not allocated to *READ ONLY MEMORY*!

Better:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LINE 80

int main()
{
    char value[MAX_LINE] ="gogo";
    puts(value);
    strcpy (value, "11");
    puts(value);
    fgets(value, MAX_LINE, stdin);
    puts(value);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is a good link with more details: [Storage for Strings in C](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/storage-for-strings-in-c/)

PS:

gets() is Evil.  Avoid it if at all possible: [Why gets() is bad](http://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?answer=1049157810&id=1043284351)